# Getting error ".map is not a function" and I can't get information from mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, mongoose

I am working with/learning `react` and `mongo`/`mongoose`. I am trying to pull some data from my database and put it on the page, but I'm getting the error:

> this.state.stories.map is not a function.

Below is the most relevant piece of code. There are obviously more files to this, but I'm not completely sure WHAT exactly is the problem and how much of the code should be included.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DeleteBtn from "../../components/DeleteBtn";
import Jumbotron from "../../components/Jumbotron";
import API from "../../utils/API";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Col, Row, Container } from "../../components/Grid";
import { List, ListItem } from "../../components/List";
import { Input, TextArea, FormBtn } from "../../components/Form";

class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    stories: [],
    offset: 0,
    author: "",
    title: "",
    genre: "",
    text: ""

  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.latestStories(this.state.offset);
  }

  latestStories = offset => {
    API.getLatestStories(offset)
      .then(res =>
        this.setState({ stories: res.data, title: "", author: "", genre: "", text: "" })
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  handleInputChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  handleFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.title && this.state.author && this.state.genre && this.state.text) {
      API.saveStory({
        title: this.state.title,
        author: this.state.author,
        genre: this.state.genre,
      })
        .then(res => this.latestStories())
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container fluid>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newStoryModal">
        NEW STORY
        </button>
        <div class="modal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" id="newStoryModal">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                      <Input
                        value={this.state.author}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        name="author"
                        placeholder="Author Name"
                      />
                      <Input
                        value={this.state.title}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        name="title"
                        placeholder="title here"
                      />
                      <Input
                        value={this.state.genre}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        name="genre"
                        placeholder="genre"
                      />
                      <TextArea
                        value={this.state.text}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        name="text"
                        placeholder="story here"
                        maxLength= "500"
                        rows= "10"
                      />
                      <FormBtn
                        disabled={!(this.state.author && this.state.title)}
                        onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}
                      >
                        Submit Story
                      </FormBtn>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <Row>
          <Col size="md-6">
            <Jumbotron>
              <h1>LATEST STORIES</h1>
            </Jumbotron>
            {this.state.stories.length ? (
              <List>
                {this.state.stories.map(story => (
                  <ListItem key={story._id}>
                    <Link to={"/stories/" + story.id}>
                      <strong>
                        {story.title} by {story.author}
                      </strong>
                    </Link>
                    <DeleteBtn onClick={() => this.deleteBook(story._id)} />
                  </ListItem>
                ))}
              </List>
            ) : (
              <h3>No Results to Display</h3>
            )}
          </Col>
            
          <Col size="md-6 sm-12">
            
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

After a lot of googling (hours) it looks like this kind of error usually arises if you try to use the function with something that isn't an array. I put a `console.log` of the state inside the `componentDidMount`, but I got the initial empty array (probably due to the asynchronous call). I thought maybe it was getting something undefined from the `API` call, and tried putting a `console.log` in the query itself, but I don't see the res come up anywhere.

```js
  latestStories: function(req, res) {
    console.log(res);
    db.Stories
      .find(req.query)
      .sort({ date: -1 })
      .limit(5)
      .skip(req.params.offset)
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  }
```

I have `robomongo`/`robo3T` open, and it seems either I don't know how to find my database, or that it doesn't exist. I'm running `mongo`, and I'm not getting any errors related to the database, but I can't seem to get what I want from it. I considered that perhaps my seed wasn't being used, though I see it referenced in the **package.json**.

Comment: try console logging your response to see if you're getting any response

Comment: I did try, but it seems not to be console logging at all.

Comment: so there must be a problem with how  you've connected to robomongo.